# Laravel Get All Children Under Parent

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

In my database I have Categories, and they can have child categories. Categories also have products. Ex:

```
Category
    Sub-Category 1
      Product 1
        Sub-Sub-Category 1
            Product 2
            Product 3
```

**Category Model**

```php
public function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products');
}
```

My question is if I do $Category->products, I want it to give me all the products. If I do $Sub-Sub-Category-1, it gives me product 2 and product 3. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No relationship would accomplish that, you'd likely want some sort of recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

just a sample recursive method according to what [daven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470327/laravel-get-all-children-under-parent#comment95748684_54470327) commented.

It is not tested but the idea behind it is to grab all subcategories and select all of their products recursively.

```php
    public function allProducts()
    {
        //call recursive method to append all children categories
        return $this->getAll([$this])
            //select category products as each item
            ->pluck('products')
            //flatten products into one dimension array
            ->flatten()
            //remove repeated products
            ->unique();
    }

    public function getAll($categories)
    {
        //appending categories array
        $append = collect();
        //walk-through input categories
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            //if category has children add them to $append
            if ($category->childs()->count())
            {
                $append->merge($category->childs);
            }
        }
        //if there were children categories, also add their children to $append
        if ($append->count())
        {
            $append = $this->getAll($append);
        }
        //merge children and categories
        return $categories->merge($append);
    }
```